# Most robust method for converting US architectural units to decimal?

Tags: php, validation

I apologize if this is too easy of a concept, but here's what I have.

I'm taking inputs in the format of U.S. architectural units and trying to convert them to decimal units.

For example these are some inputs:

- 9' 0"
- 12' 11-0"
- 1' 0-1/2"
- 0' 10-5/8"

As you can see the demarcations are never in the same spot, so if I try to base the function on location, it get's big and messy pretty quick. I'm also hitting walls with "divide by zero" without some over-the-top character checking.

chances are I've been staring at this too long and have over-complicated my efforts. I'm using PHP and MySQL if that has any bearing on the answer(s).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)? Something along the line:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)\' ([0-9]+)(?:-(?:0|([0-9])\/([0-9]{1,2})))?\"?/', '1\' 0-1/2"', $matches);
$foot = intval($matches[1], 10);
$inch = intval($matches[2], 10);
$inch_suf1 = 0;
$inch_suf2 = 1;
if (count($matches) > 3) {
    $inch_suf1 = intval($matches[3], 10);
    if (count($matches) > 4)) {
        $inch_suf2 = intval($matches[4], 10);
    }
}
$inch = $inch + $inch_suf1 / $inch_suf2;
echo sprintf("%d feet and %.4f inch\n", $foot, $inch);
```

This assumes that all input is of the form you suggest, that is, no further checking here...

The match will get all the numbers from the string and convert them to integers, then calculate the exact number of inches into a float (or integer if it remains a whole number).

**Edit:** updated the RegExp to recognize the fraction part and make ending " optional and added ' inch' to the output string.

Comment: I tried this on: `array(19) { ["pf"]=> string(6) " 13' 1" ["sf"]=> string(6) " 13' 6" ["pm"]=> string(6) " 13' 2" ["sm"]=> string(10) " 13' 5-1/8" ["pa"]=> string(10) " 13' 2-1/2" ["sa"]=> string(10) " 13' 6-1/4" ... }` and got the response: `1 feet and 1.0000` for each measurement

Comment: In your question, you did not specify that the ending `"` was optional. I've now updated the answer for that. Also, the fraction part is now optional. The code now works for all input values you commented.